# can't find saved entity in test

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing

I'm testing my spring application, but there is wired thing. I can't find out why this happens.

in my spring code, I save requestBody into db using crudRepository. and I could find saved item with crudRepository.
but when I run unittest and invoke same method with TestRestTemplate, I can't find saved item with crudRepository.

server

```
@PostMapping("")
    public Question saveQuestion(@RequestBody Question question) {
        questionRepository.save(question);

        for(Question _p:questionRepository.findAll()) {
            Application.LOG.info("[saveQuestion] "+_p.toString());
        }
        // I can find saved Question
        return question;
    }
```

unittest

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Transactional
public class QuestionControllerTest {
    @Autowired TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Autowired QuestionRepository questionRepository;
@Test
    public void addNewQuestionTest() throws InterruptedException {
        String json= "{\"uniqueId\":1}";

        HttpEntity<String> req = new HttpEntity<>(json, headers);

        ResponseEntity<Question> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("/question", req, Question.class);

        for(Question _p:questionRepository.findAll()) {
            Application.LOG.info("[addNewQuestion]"+_p.toString());
        }
        // I can't find saved question.
    }
}
```

log looks like this.

```
[saveQuestion] Question(0)
[saveQuestion] Question(1)
[addNewQuestionTest] Question(0)
```

but I excepted

```
[saveQuestion] Question(0)
[saveQuestion] Question(1)
[addNewQuestionTest] Question(0)
[addNewQuestionTest] Question(1)
```

I checked db has data and saveQuestion method prints 2 items.
but there is only 1 item in addNewQuestionTest method.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just an assumption but might be happening here is a follows:

**1)** You have marked the entire test to be run under a certain transaction:

```
@Transactional
public class QuestionControllerTest {
```

**2)** When you hit the post method, it saves the entity but within its own / new transaction

```
ResponseEntity<Question> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("/question", req, Question.class);
```

The transaction from 1) is still active here, so you have 2 transactions.

**3)** As the save has been performed in a separate transaction while the first one is still active, the first one does not yet access to the data saved by transaction 2).

**Solution**

As Spring JPA repositories are Transactional by nature i would remove the `@Transactional` from the test configuration.

Now, when you hit the `questionRepository.findAll()`, it would triggered a new transaction which would have access to the data saved by the first transaction persisting the questionarre.

Comment: OMG. when i removed @Transactional, tests pass well.
thanks you so much. I need to learn more about JPA and Transactional